# Does gremlin support the bulkloader with neptune?

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

Neptune's newest update includes bulkload with a CSV file. Does the js lv of Gremlin support this?

Comment: This is probably better asked on Gremlin's GH issues page.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understand your question but Amazon Neptune has always had a Bulk Loader that can load vertices and edges that are stored in CSV files. Once loaded you will have a property graph that any of the Gremlin GLV clients can work with. The documentation is located here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/bulk-load.html

EDITED to add that the bulk loader is controlled by an HTTP/REST endpoint so you could invoke it from within you code but not using the `g.io()` step currently.